# Sorm Bolts execute method working

Tags: apache-storm

My understanding of Storm Bolt's execute method is -
(assuming there is only one task and three tuples)

1. Execute method of the bolt is called passing the first tuple
2. Once the method completes and returns the Execute method of the bolt is called passing the Second tuple and so on
3. In case the first tuple ack fails the first tuple goes back to the queue. The processing continues with second and third tuple
4. The execute method is called passing the first tuple again at the end

Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 1):

Basically yes.

However, if first tuple fails, it is not "put back to the queue" but a callback to `Spout.fail(Object msgId)` will be performed (for all "parent tuples" of the first tuple. On this, the Spout will re-emit all parent tuples. And thus, the exact order when the tuple will be handed to `execute()` is not predictable exactly.

Of course, your Spout must be a so-called reliable Spout, ie, must store all data reliably such that it can re-emit all failing tuples. Many provided Spouts are reliable.

For more details, look into Storm documentation: https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html